# Regular Expression for Subdomain

Tags: regex, iis-7, url-rewriting

I was hoping you could help me with a regular expression I'm having trouble writing for my subdomain.

The basic format of my domain will be something like this:

```
http://xxxxxxx-md.mywebsite.com
```

The `http://` is optional and the `xxxxxxxx` is not a set length and hasn't any restrictions (yet!). The only thing I need to check for is the `-md` which will always be at the end of the subdomain.

At the moment, this is what I've got but I don't think it's working properly.

```
(http:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9]*|(\W)-md.mywebsite.com(\W)
```

Can you take a look and advise please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current regex will match either:

```
(http:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

OR

```
(\W)-md.mywebsite.com(\W)
```

Which is not what you probably want. Use a group to restrict the `OR`:

```
(http:\/\/)?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]*|(\W))-md.mywebsite.com
```

And you want a single non-alphanumeric, digit, underscore in the `xxxxx` part? If you want  to allow more, you'd use:

```
(http:\/\/)?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]*|\W*)-md.mywebsite.com
```

Or perhaps:

```
(http:\/\/)?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]|\W)*-md.mywebsite.com
```

Oh and I removed the `(\W)` part because it doesn't seem useful, unless you had a purpose for it.